# How to properly inject app element in webpack? - Receiving [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4, ts-loader

Here is my code [code example](https://github.com/Mark41/vue-test/tree/41b4f54bde643d1cd02af1610aded9e7d34000c6)

I am trying to learn webpack 4 and am setting up a test project.

Traditionally I have built vuejs app inside Asp.net websites.  So I always know the entry html point and can put the  element on the page.

From all the blog post I have seen for vue this seems to be all they do to setup their app.

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
    <div id='app'>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

**index.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: (h) => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

When I run this I get [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app.  If I add

```
 document.write('<div id="app"><router-view></router-view></div>');
```

The code runs fine.  Since I am using vue-router, I don't think I actually need the App.vue file, but I still need someplace to mount the vue object too.

So looking at my github link, what would be the correct way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [chicken-and-egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) problem. You're trying to amount the root component to the `#app` div, but the `#app` div exists inside the `App` component. At the time when you call `new Vue` the `#app` div doesn't exist because the `App` component hasn't mounted!

Most Vue apps have an empty `<div id="app"></div>` in the `index.html` file so that the root Vue component has somewhere to mount to when the page has loaded.

If you don't want to do it that way then you can mount it manually instead:

```es6
const root = new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
  router
}).$mount()

document.body.appendChild(root.$el)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thats what I figured.  I found out how to modify the index.html that html-webpack-plugin generates. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Updated code is here if anyone is interested. [code](https://github.com/Mark41/vue-test/tree/0f1b66a570a42effea6cb2c99c7c09bc019f7ecc)